# CSS Grid - Mood board design

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create a layout like this mood board with CSS grids:

[image]

I would like each section to be a picture & link.

I can't seem to get it to work, although I'm not the biggest Grids expert. I can't seem to find anything when searching online.

Is this possible or a pipedream? Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Hi Erin, welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is definitely achievable with CSS.  I'd love to help out, can you please post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

With background image:

```css
.container {
  width:410px;
  height:610px;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:10px;
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
}

.div1, .div2, .div3, .div4{
  background:#e0e0e0;
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.div1 {
  background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
}

.div2 {
  background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/500');
}

.div3 {
  background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/700');
}

.div4 {
  background:url('https://picsum.photos/400/800');
}

.circle {
  height:220px;
  width:220px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: radial-gradient(#e0e0e0 0px, #e0e0e0 100px, #fff 100px, #fff 110px);
}

.circle_bg {
  position:absolute;
  background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/200');
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle_bg"></div>
</div>
```

Same as your showed:

```css
.container {
  width:410px;
  height:610px;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:10px;
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
}

.div1, .div2, .div3, .div4{
  background:#e0e0e0;
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
}

.circle {
  height:220px;
  width:220px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: radial-gradient(#e0e0e0 0px, #e0e0e0 100px, #fff 100px, #fff 110px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a 2x2 CSS grid, set thick white borders for the 4 divs, then put a 5th div outside the grid with higher z-index on the center, with a transparent 50% border-radius border, white background, and a thick padding, and then center the image. So basically you just cover the center of your simple 2x2 grid.